# Can anybody please tell me why my query fails in Cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I am trying to Left join some queries and I am getting some errors. It will run for the first time and when I ran it for the second time it gave me a different error message. Then I try to run it for the 3rd time, it gave me another different error. I could not capture 1 st error.

Is there any other better solution or better way to achieve this?

I did some research for this error, I am pretty sure it not something with time or limits since it runs few times.

[image]
[image]
[image]

2nd Error
[image]

Please tell me if the there better and efficient way I can do this.

Thank you

Comment: What did the error messages say?  The first thing to do when you run into errors is to read the messages and, if necessary, go into the log file to see what's there.  Also it could be possible that this sort of modelling would be better done in your modelling tool.  I don't know what your model looks like so I can't pass judgement about whether what you are trying isn't actually conflicting with what is modelled. As a rule of thumb, avoid outer joins.  Talk to your modelling counterpart.  If this sort of thing needs to be implemented then it is better done in a model or via ETL in the db.

Comment: The joins are probably not the problem.  It looks like there is a syntax error in a data item expression.

Comment: @dougp, what do you mean by syntax error. Each individual query run fine and i will get the result. I think the issue when is last join. MD_AI and CI_class. Somehow it does not like it. Thank you

Comment: Can you run the report for small set of rows you are familiar with?
Try adding a filter like this   [Employee Number] IN (123,456,789)

Let me know if the report runs in that example
1) It could be that the query takes too long to execute
2) Another possibility is record locks - is the data source used only for reporting or is this shared with production/transactional database where it competes for access?
If so, what is your cursor isolation level (see if you can change it to Read Uncommitted (aka dirty read)

Comment: For MD_AI and CI_class 
What are the data types (string, numeric, decimal, etc) for Company and Employee Number?  Are they the same types for BOTH tables?  For example if Company on MD_AI is character and CI_class it is numeric, that will potentially cause issues

Comment: Please define "run".  Are you running the report, running the page, or using "view tabular data" on the query?  Did you use the same method all three times?  What type of visualization does the query feed?  Cognos makes decisions and writes code based on the design of the entire report and the context of how you are running it, not just what is in the query.

Comment: What version of Cognos are you using?  I see you have tagged this with `cognos-10` and `cognos-11`.  Does that mean you have tried it in both environments and get the same results?

Comment: Can you kindly post the error the is being masked by CAF?  https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/dpr-err-2082-complete-error-has-been-logged-caf-secureerrorid

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for your help. This is really weird. I was working at night, but when I ran the same report in the morning no issue. I don't know what happens. Again, thank you for you all help

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you started
We want to find out where the error is occuring

Is it the data?  Could there be unexpected data?  Unusual characters that break a join? the model? the report? etc

1. Do not delete your work

Copy your report and use that to experiment.  This way you can always get back to your starting point

2. Divide and conquer

Take each of the queries as a separate list - no joins

Do the individual lists run?

Does the data look the way you would expect?

3. Run over a small, known part of the data

Can you run a filtered request that just returns a few rows of data you are familiar with?

Like company 1, employee 123, year 2021, month 6
If the query works.

Then run it with the filters more open (like all employees).
If it breaks, probably something in the data that needs to be handled

4. Check for scenarios

For example,
Try the report where you would get a null due to an outer join